# C++ - Using list<> in struct to create a tree structure

Tags: list, c++11, gcc, struct, tree

I've been using a `std::list<>` inside of a `struct` to create a tree-like structure. This compiles (`-std=c++11`) and runs no problem but I have always been worried about it because it didn't look quite right. Lately my code started to give me a segmentation fault and the stack shows the issue is occurring from the destructors in the lists. Below is a code snippet of what I am doing:

```
#include <string>
#include <list>

struct Node
{
    std::string Key;
    std::string Value;
    std::list<Node> Children;

    Node() {}
    Node(std::string key, std::string value)
     : Key(key), Value(value) {}
};
```

Here is the stack trace I am getting from GDB (what is below and repeats several times):

```
> malloc_consolidate()
> _int_free()
> __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_List_node<Node> >::deallocate()
> std::__cxx11::_List_base<Node, std::allocator<Node> >::_M_put_node()
> std::__cxx11::_List_base<Node, std::allocator<Node> >::_M_clear()
> std::__cxx11::_List_base<Node, std::allocator<Node> >::~_List_base()
> std::__cxx11::list<Node, std::allocator<Node> >::~list()
> Node::~Node()
> ...
```

The spot in malloc.c where it crashes from `malloc_consolidate()` is line 4163 at `nextsize = chunksize(nextchunk);`. Below is the portion from malloc.c where the segmentation fault occurs (GCC v5.2):

```
/* Slightly streamlined version of consolidation code in free() */
size = p->size & ~(PREV_INUSE|NON_MAIN_ARENA);
nextchunk = chunk_at_offset(p, size);
nextsize = chunksize(nextchunk);   // **Segmentation fault on this line!!!
```

Like I've said I have been using this for awhile but lately it is giving me run-time errors in only one spot in my code. My thought is that as the destructors for the `std::list<>` objects are called eventually this will hit a point where there are lists with no objects, `Node::Children.size() = 0`, and memory cleanup shouldn't be an issue since there shouldn't be any infinite recursion in doing so. If I'm missing something please let me know.

### Update:

As stated in the comment by Igor Tandetnik I did have a memory bug in another section of code which loosely was tied to editing data inside of my `struct Node`. I have corrected the bug and everything works correctly. I'm not going to go through the details of my solution since it is very specific to my code only, but to others reading this and having a similar issue look at all functions which touch or modify the `struct` and see if there are any memory issues. Look for dynamic memory, pointers being misused, etc. I know everyone's scenario is specific to their own code but hopefully the above tips make this easier for you.

Comment: You want to create m-ary tree?

Comment: In short, yes. This is meant to store XML into a data structure. I'd like to use the C++11 STL so I do not have to worry about memory management.

Comment: My educated guess would be, you have a heap corruption bug somewhere, quite possibly in a completely unrelated piece of code. `Node`'s destructor simply has the misfortune to be the first to stumble upon the corrupted data structure.

Comment: I think you should put trace log to know when these `Node` is free. Try to minimize the code as much as possible

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik: You are correct, there was a memory bug in another piece of my code. The code isn't really related on the surface although if I dug down more I'd find the connection. I fixed this bug and now everything works correctly.